# Comparar dos array y si son diferentes los id_programa asignar el id del segundo array como undefined (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches tengo dos array el cual tiene diferente id_programa con un id y otro array con el mmismo id pero diferente id_programa, mi pregunta es como le hago para conservar los id de los primero array y eliminar los del segundo?

```js
//Conservar los id de los primeros array
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: true}
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: true}

//Cambiar por undefined los id si los id_programa son diferente del primero.
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}

//Quede asi:
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
```

Comment: Creo que te faltó poner los [ ] ?? o no?. Además creo haber entenido que quieres el segundo array que todos los id's sean undefined o es otra cosa?

Comment: Objeto de objetos... Array de objetos... el OP nunca lo menciona :s

Comment: Perdón no soy muy bueno explicando :( , pero son el primer array, el segundo y el último es el resultado esperado, quise editar mi pregunta pero no me dejo me marco error :/

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, solo faltó aclarar algunos detalles =)

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo de verdad agradezco tu ayuda de bastante, en serio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método [**`some()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) para que verifiques si los valores de `id_programa_educativo` son distintos o iguales. Dependiendo a esto va a cambiar el valor de `id` a `undefined` en donde al final te devolverá el mismo objeto con estos cambios. Veamos:

```js
const obj = {
  0: { id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: true },
  1: { id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: true },
};

// Obtenemos los valores de los objetos => [38, 39]
let result = Object.values(obj).map(valor => valor.id_programa_educativo);

// Con some(), llevamos al result a una función llamada "repetido", donde verificará si estos son iguales.
let verificar = result.some(repetido);

// El resultado de la función se almacenará en "verificar".
function repetido(valor, indice, lista) {
  return !(lista.indexOf(valor) === indice);
}

// Si "verificar" es false (osea, si son distintos), entrará en esta condición.
if (!verificar) {
  // Recorremos a los objetos para cambiar los valores de "id" a undefined.
  for (const i in obj) {
    obj[i].id = undefined;
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo @Cris223511, pero en este caso son dos array como hago para hacer la comparación? {id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}, si estos queiro sean undefined??

Comment: Mmmm según entendí, si los valores de `id_programa_educativo` son distintos, el valor de `id` sería undefined, no de dos arreglos... además nunca supe si era arreglo de objetos u objeto de objetos... pero traté de acercarme más a tu solución, recuerda explicar más a detalle tus preguntas =) saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo @Cris223511.dev , asi coo hiciste el const obj asi son dos el cual el primero se respeta y el segundo si el id_programa es diferente del primer arreglo el id del segundo arreglo pasa a undefined y este se almacenaría en un nuevo arreglo. Perdón soy malo explicando y lamento no poder explicar mejor pero llevo todo el dia con este inconveniente :(

Comment: Te super agradeceria muchisimo tu ayuda amigo @Cris223511.dev